# ony-if-cached errors: implementing caching with retrofit

Tags: android, caching, kotlin

I am relatively new to coding/android development and I am trying to implement caching for the first time in my app. The app currently makes database calls every time it is opened to get some basic information that could easily be cached and stored between sessions.

I figured the easiest solution would be to implement caching with retrofit as outlined here: https://medium.com/mindorks/caching-with-retrofit-store-responses-offline-71439ed32fda I wanted to be able to modify this to check if there was non-expired data in the cache and only make the database call if the data was expired. As opposed to using the cache if the phone was offline.

So far this is what I have

```
OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(timeout.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS).run {
        context?.let { context ->
                cache(Cache(context.cacheDir, (5 * 1024 * 1024).toLong()))
                addInterceptor {
                    it.proceed(it.request().newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "private, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60*60*24*28).build())
                }
```

I was hoping that this would check if there was data in the cache and then make the call if there wasn't, but instead I get a 504 error response from the database. I figure that I am missing some key steps, but I am not sure what they are. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the ins and outs of how each interceptor works, but I fiddled/searched around until I found something that worked for me using two Interceptors. Part of my implementation was to be able to force a refresh, which is the boolean you see in the first interceptor

Kotlin:

```
...
val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(timeUnit.toSeconds(cacheDuration), TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

cache(Cache(File(context?.cacheDir, "http-cache"), CACHE_SIZE.toLong()))
// Adding both interceptors ensures the FORCE_NETWORK to call the api through the network and override the cache with new data
addInterceptor { chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", if (!useCache) CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK.toString() else cacheControl.toString()).build()) }
//The 'Pragma' header key has a no-cache value in some APIs so it must be removed for us to cache it
addNetworkInterceptor { chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request()).newBuilder().removeHeader("Pragma").header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString()).build() }
...
```